# EJB exception while try to run the client

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, ejb

I created a bean object and encountered this error at run time,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException at 
com.sun.corba.se.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(Unknown Source) at 
javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(Unknown Source) at Client_TestPortal.main Client_TestPortal.java:71) Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference ... 3 more
```

How to create bean object in my client? I have, a bean Interface, `TestPortal`, and a bean class, `TestPortalBean`, in an ear, `PortalEJB`.

Here is the code, I am using to create EJB instance in client,

```
String sEjbRemote = "PortalEJB/TestPortalBean/remote";

Properties pProp = new Properties();
pProp.put("java.naming.factory.initial",sInitCtxtCls);
pProp.put("java.naming.provider.url", sUrl);

javax.naming.InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(pProp);
Object ref = initialContext.lookup(sEjbRemote);
System.out.println("\n\n \t Source :::"+ref.toString());

test.ejb.TestPortal testportal = (test.ejb.TestPortal)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ref,test.ejb.TestPortal.class);
```

Object ref = initialContext.lookup(sEjbRemote);

When i print the object in SOP ref.toString();

i got the following information but i am not able to create object for TestPortal which is in the PoratlEJB.ear which is deployed in JBOSS- AS version : Jboss-5.0.1.GA

```
     Source :::Reference Class Name: Proxy for: test.ejb.TestPortal
```

Type: ProxyFactoryKey
Content: ProxyFactory/TestPortalBean/PortalEJB/TestPortalBean/remote
Type: EJB Container Name
Content: jboss.j2ee:ear=PortalEJB.ear,jar=PortalEJB.jar,name=TestPortalBean,serv
ice=EJB3
Type: Proxy Factory is Local
Content: false
Type: Remote Business Interface
Content: test.ejb.TestPortal
Type: Remoting Host URL
Content: socket://s9458:3973/

Comment: How are you creating the object in client? Show some code here.

Comment: What are you using? J2ee 1.4? Java EE 5/6? Web interface? Remote rich client?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, we do something like this,

```
Properties props = getConfigurationProps();
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
tp = (TestPortal) ctx.lookup(TEST_PORTAL_JNDI_NAME);
```

**[Edited]**

From your code I can see that you are trying to `narrow()` the object. Lets see what documentation is saying regarding this, it says,

---

```
Checks to ensure that an object of a remote or abstract interface type can be cast to a desired type. 

Parameters:
    narrowFrom - the object to check.
    narrowTo - the desired type. 
Returns:
    an object which can be cast to the desired type. 
Throws: 
    ClassCastException - if narrowFrom cannot be cast to narrowTo.
```

---

I am not sure what are you up to. But you can always do this, in the first place, as I have already shown in my first attempt.

```
TestPortal ref = (TestPortal) initialContext.lookup(sEjbRemote);
```

instead of,

```
Object ref = initialContext.lookup(sEjbRemote);
```

Comment: @saran: Added your code to your original question. You can do the same in future, by clicking the edite link given, on the bottom-left of your question.

Comment: @Saran: Now you can delete your comments from here, as they are no more relevant. I would do that too, including this one.

Comment: @Saran: I have updated my answer, accordingly, after looking at your code.

Comment: Adeel,    When i try this below code 

TestPortal ref = (TestPortal) initialContext.lookup(sEjbRemote);


i got the following Error:



Client_TestPortal.java:61: cannot access TestPortal
bad class file: .\TestPortal.java
file does not contain class TestPortal
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpa
th.
                                TestPortal ref = (TestPortal) initialContext.loo
kup(sEjbRemote);
                                ^
1 error

Comment: @Saran: Is your interface and class, both, `public`?